# How early does it make sense to apply for a job?

Tags: software-industry, applications, germany, europe

I'm a software engineer, planning to switch jobs. As I'm currently employed, I'll need at least 3 months to cancel my contract, but probably more to responsibly finish my current projects and tasks. Then I'd like a 2-3 months off to "recharge" before starting another job. This means I'd start my new job not earlier than in 6 months.

Does it make sense to start applying already?

I'd like to have a long-term plan, avoid being jobless for too long and also avoid the stress of looking for a job while being unemployed. On the other hand, I don't know if companies seriously consider applicants that can start only after such a delay.

Comment: If you downvote, _please comment on why_. Otherwise the question can't be improved and I can't learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: I think 2-3 months to "recharge" is a bit excessive. Perhaps a month. I assume that you are quite well qualified so getting a new job within a month will be fine

Comment: 2-3 months to recharge is very excessive in my opinion, when i changed jobs a month or so ago i thought 2 weeks was a lot.

Comment: @EdHeal "I think 2-3 months to "recharge" is a bit excessive?" -- Why do you think that? I guess this is based on your personal opinion and is besides not the question the OP asked.

Comment: 2-3 months between jobs require a bit more explication than 28 days

Comment: For contractors having 2-3 months as a break between  contract sis not unusual

Comment: @EdHeal - it entirely depends on the industry, individual, the work they were doing before leaving, how long ago it was since their last longish break, and what they plan on doing during the "recharge".

Comment: I agree that 2-3 months may seem a lot, but I have personal reasons for that, which are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Pepone - Is that going from one contract job to another? The OP wants to look for another job before being unemployed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only general answer here is: **it depends**.

- It depends on the size of your next employer. Larger companies with a large number of developers have long-term plans. They will be fine with hiring a new person starting half a year from now. Smaller companies that just found out their 3 developers won't be ready in time for the deadline won't have that long-term planning. They might want someone *now*, or probably *yesterday*.
- It depends on what is normal in your country. Where I live, notice periods of 6 week to 6 months are normal. Looking for a job to start 6 months from now is somewhat normal. In a country where you have two weeks notice maximum, companies may not understand the 6 months.
- It depends on how comfortable you are looking for a new job while unemployed and if you can actually "recharge" without a set future. Some people can, some cannot.

There is no harm in sending out applications now. Make sure you mention your starting date. You cannot know what companies consider a good starting date, but I have not heard of anyone having a blacklist for people that applied to early.  Worst case, they don't hire you right now. You can always try again later.

**Germany**

As you have tagged this Germany, let me add some specifics for Germany: It's not uncommon to have 6 months notice period. It's not uncommon to take time off between jobs to do the things you'd never be able to do while employed (for example a trip to Australia). As long as you state your starting date clearly, you will be fine. As an employer, I will not *get* anyone earlier, simply because for the job I'm offering the people need experience. You only get experience by being employed for a long time and being employed for a long time means your employer is eager to keep you *and* you have a 6 months notice period. The only way to grab someone earlier is if another company goes bankrupt or the person is leaving his job for personal reasons (for example long-distance relationships that marry and move in together where one of the partners has to leave his or her city and likely employer) where his ex-employer may agree to shorten the notice period.

**TL;DR:**

Apply now. State your start date. Worst case is they pick someone else. But that's the same result as if you had not applied at all, so go for it.

Comment: This is the right answer for Germany. Most long term employees here have a notice period of 3 month so mentioning an earliest starting date in about 4-5 month is not unusual at all. Also, when I applied for my current job, they asked me if I might be able to start sooner than the date mentioned in my application (which was 5 month away) and I said I couldn't because I wanted to finish my projects for the next release of my old employer's software product. They were very understanding and hired me anyway, because it's nice to have employees who are considerate about project schedules.

Answer (score 3):

Some positions in the UK can have 6 month notice periods, so it may not be completely unreasonable but it would depend on the company as to whether or not they are willing to wait that long.

You could possibly just sell it that your notice period is 6 months and not mention your break. Or when asked "How long is the notice period at your current job" answer with "I can start work in 6 months". If they push for details you can explain that you'll be required to finish up your current projects to a point where they can be handed over.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what country you are in. Here in the U.S., employers routinely expect a new employee to start within 2 weeks. The expectation is that when you quit your current job, you will give 2 weeks notice, and then start the new job fairly promptly after that.

I once told a prospective employer that I wouldn't be able to start for 4 weeks, and this was a big problem that may have come close to costing me the job. I am unlikely to ever do that again.

I think few employers would be interested in an employee who can't start for six months. There are exceptions, like teachers are often expected to start with a new school year rather than immediately. But those are exceptions, not the general rule.

If you're really planning to take off 2 or 3 months to "recharge" before starting the new job, I'd delay looking until I was in a position where I was ready to start within 2 or 3 weeks of getting an offer. Of course that creates the problem that if it takes you 6 months to get an offer, you may be running out of money to live on. I really don't know how you would reconcile that. Personally, I have never had more than a few days between jobs of my own volition. (I got fired once and it took me a month or so to find a new job, but that was not by my choice.)

Comment: In some country's less than a month s notice would indicate you where unskilled blue collar labour

Comment: @pepone That's why I was careful to say "in the U.S." I suppose that in any culture there is likely to be some outer limit. Like, is there anywhere in the world where it's routinely accepted that after being offered a job you won't actually start for 5 years? But 2 weeks seems a pretty short amount of time to me. I'd be interested to hear what the norm is in other countries.